# How do you do mysqldump in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

And how do I restore from my dump back to the db?

Comment: The title is confusing - can you update it with something like "How do you restore a PostgreSQL database?"

Comment: Title might be confusing if you have never used mysql.  It's pretty much exactly my search terms that brought me to this page.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should have a look at the [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) and [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) commands.

```
pg_dump - extract a PostgreSQL database into a script file or other archive file.

pg_restore - restore a PostgreSQL database from an archive file created by pg_dump.
```

Comment: `su postgres -c pg_dumpall > dump.sql`

Answer (score 6):

Please look at [`pg_dump(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pg_dump) and [`pg_restore(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pg_restore).

Comment: Anything wrong with the original "man" pages at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/reference-client.html ?